# GUI IDE with PyDev Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, user-interface, ide, pydev

I have 2 weeks to finish my final year project.I need a GUI IDE or a GUI framework compatible with PyDev and Eclipse.

I cannot spend time learning something cause the functionality is yet to be completed.I'm looking for very simple GUI for a simulation game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyQt is the fastest GUI toolkit to develop with IMO, partly because you can use [Qt Designer](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) to design your GUI instead of coding it by hand.

You may want to also check out pygame - http://www.pygame.org/news.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to integrate PYQT with Eclipse

Comment: If you are using eclipse with the pydev plugin, you can edit python files. To create and modify the GUI, 007brendan is suggesting you use Qt Designer. To repeat others, _there is no GUI builder in eclipse_ (except for Visual Editor that was abandoned last time I looked).

Answer (score 2):

> I need a GUI IDE or a GUI framework compatible with PyDev and Eclipse.

There is **no** Eclipse embedded GUI editor for any of the Python GUI frameworks, but it's not so bad. Do you really *need* for it to be integrated on Eclipse?

The closest you  can get is may be use [Jython](http://wiki.python.org/jython/) and use some swing GUI editor.

Depending on the framework you want to use (GTK+/QT3/QT4/wxWidgets) you'll get to choose a graphical GUI editor.

> I cannot spend time learning something cause the functionality is yet to be completed.

It doesn't matter what tool we give you, **you are going to have to learn to use it**.

> I'm looking for very simple GUI for a simulation game.

If what you want is to develop is a game, you should take a look at [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) (*[must read](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html)*) and [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d.org/), although [there a lot more others](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries).

Answer (score 1):

This page  http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming  has a fairly complete list of gui frameworks and gui builders.  I don't have too much experience with building gui's, but I've done a little bit with WxPython and PyQt.  Both seem fairly easy to get a basic gui going quickly.

I haven't used a gui builder, but hand coding a gui in python is not nearly as painful as it is in other languages in my opinion, so I don't think they are really necessary for a simple gui.

Also, I think either of these frameworks would be compatible with PyDev and Eclipse.  You just have to install the library and import them into your existing code.

Comment: There is some compatibility problem of wxpython with Eclipe PyDev or just python version.I'm yet to figure this out.Still searching PYQT integration wil Eclipse

Comment: What problems are you having?  I would also recommend you try PyQt first, it makes a little more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed mine folowing this [tutorial](http://popdevelop.com/2010/04/setting-up-ide-and-creating-a-cross-platform-qt-python-gui-application/). give it a try